# ASP.NET Core with Angular CLI and Live Reload

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular-cli

I'm trying to set up an ASP.NET Core project with an Angular CLI generated Angular app.

I have the two things set up so that I can:

- Start and debug the server (ASP.NET Core) via F5 in VS Code
- Build the Angular app and watch for changes using `ng build --watch` via the terminal.

Now, I'd like to combine these two things, so that the Angular files are automatically built and watched when I'm debugging the ASP.NET Core project. But I'm not sure how to. I've tried this in my `.csproj`-file:

```
<Target Name="PostcompileScript" AfterTargets="Build">
 <Exec Command="ng build --watch" />
</Target>
```

But that will get stuck on the `watch` part and not continue debugging the project.

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

What I'm aiming for:

- An Angular application hosted in an ASP.NET Core project (instead of `ng serve`)
- Using `ng build` instead of running custom webpack scripts
- Some kind of Live Reload so that changes to my `ts` files are automatically updated in the browser while debugging.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**

I don't think it is relevant, but here is my angular cli config file:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "my-app"
    },
    "apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "wwwroot",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "content/imgs",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "app.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "content/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "testing": "environments/environment.testing.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "scss",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

And the `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>


<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PostcompileScript" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="ng build --watch" />
</Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: update the post with the config file

Comment: @Aravind The angular cli config? Why is that relevant?

Comment: of course it is relevant.

Comment: @Aravind I have added it :) But my problem isn't that my Angular app isn't working, so the config is fine I think. My problem is how to combine the build and watch of the Angular app with debugging the ASP.Net Core project

Comment: @Joel could you share csproj file?

Comment: @ivamax9 Sure, done.

Answer (score 0):

When you are IIS is serving the angular2 application, you cannot expect it to reload the browser unless it is configured explicitly. Follow the below steps

1. Open the Internet Information Services Manager by,

   ```
   type inetmgr in the run command
   ```
2. Navigate to your site in the connections pane on the left of your IIS manager window as highlighted

[image]

3. Go to Output Caching settings and click add as highlighted below
   [image]
4. Input the interval at which caching should take place, which forces the application to refresh.

When you are using the ng serve command to execute the application you can use the below option to reload when there is a change

```
ng serve --live-reload 
      or
ng serve -lr
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I do not want to use `ng serve` (I want to use IIS with the compiled files). I wan't to find a way to run `ng build --watch` as a part of my build process, if that is possible.

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you, but the live reload part is only interesting for me during the development phase while I'm running the application via IIS Express and debugging it in VS Code. Not when deployed in production in a real IIS installation.

Comment: you can still use IIS to run your application by configuring in your web.config file. Consider this case **Currently your application runs in IIS Express. You can modify the settings in your webconfig file

Answer (score 0):

Currently I've been facing those issues, I wasn't able of getting HRM behaviour with my ASP NET Core and Angular 6 application and that is because I'm (we) are not serving the angular app, we are only building it, the static files serve is being done by dotnet instead of ng.

A temporary solution, the only one I found, is to **run ng build once you want to see your changes in your web and then refresh your browser** as soon as ng build command finish.

Another thing I've read is that it is still possible to configure webpack to be in charge of HMR but I still haven't figured out how to do it, latest solution (manual build) is working for me.

By the way, there is a project template that creates the project scaffolding for you, with ASP NET Core and Angular 6.

https://github.com/JuanGarciaCarmona/AspNetCore2Ang6Template

I hope it helps,

Juan

Comment: Late to party by many years. We’re converting an enterprise level solution into angular/net core and im facing the same problem. We’re serving the project from backend and running watch on the front end. Im trying to get hmr and live-reload working but am having zero luck. The solution is hosted on one port and apparently hmr needs the wp dev server to spin up and work. Very confused. i’ve tried for many hours to get this working.

Comment: Hi Spencer, IMHO HMR is only interesting during development phase and I always do it using ng serve. In addition, I only faced that problem with Angular 6 and it was probably due to a bad configuration at that point, TBH, I re-scaffolded the project, creating a brand new one and moving my code into it and it started to work.

Comment: Hi Juan. Yes i’m only interested because of its dev value. It saves countless hours of tedious refreshing/losing state. I can easily get it to work using only the webpack dev server… the problem is the way this is setup. The project is served with Kestrel, via net core. So, the backend, which is literally just a web api and data access layer, is serving up the site when launching from visual studio. What i want, it for it serve up with HMR enabled. I don’t think it’s possible, and it makes sense because web pack dev server is… another server. I need to find a way to proxy backend api calls.